# Click on browser back button react

Tags: reactjs, browser

I'm trying to solve the problem that when I click on the browser back button, I want to back to this path: http://localhost:3000/#/contrats, from this path: http://localhost:3000/?toto=test#/,
if there's someone who solve this issue before, what was the solution that you're implemented, I'm open to any question, and I appreciate your support.

Comment: i didn't understand your question properly but i think you want to manage that stack of pages that you lastly visited right ?

Comment: yeah , this is it , i went back to the last visited page

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way to Store your Routing Data and manage Route is to Use React Router . that will manage your routing and also gives a predefined function to go back or forward etc as per your coding . For Your Reference You Can Use [This](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/hello-react-navigation/)

This Thing is easy to implement and also you like my Answer . Thank You

Comment: I think that i don't explain clearly my situation, i'm using react-router, but when i try to go back from path1 who doesn't have any query param to path2 with query param , by clicking on browser back button , but it doesn't work. http://localhost:3000/?toto=test#/ ==> http://localhost:3000/#/contrats

Comment: bro if you are using this react navigator than there have function code like                                             this.props.navigation.popToTop()  that will redirect to last screen